# Using ArcPy cursor to insert polyline

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, array, typeerror

I'm trying to use an InsertCursor to write code where I insert a line segment from two points in the shapefile, but I keep getting a type error explained below

```
import arcpy, os, traceback

fc = 'C:/example.shp'
ogLines = 'C:/Lines.shp'
fcLine = 'C:/folder/' + os.path.basename(ogLines)
arcpy.Copy_management(ogLines, fcLine)


try:
    # get the centroid points
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@XY']) as scursor:
        # Get 2 centroids
        row = scursor.next()
        point1 = arcpy.Point(row[0][0], row[0][1])
        print('Point1: ({0},{1})'.format(row[0][0], row[0][1]))
        row = scursor.next()
        point2 = arcpy.Point(row[0][0], row[0][1])
        print('Point2: ({0},{1})'.format(row[0][0], row[0][1]))
    del scursor
except:
    print('error')
    traceback.print_exc()
    del scursor

myArray = arcpy.Array([point1, point2])
line = arcpy.Polyline(myArray)

    # Using an insert cursor to insert polyline and set value of FID to 5
try:
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcPoly, ['FID', 'SHAPE@'])
    newRow = [5, line]
    **cursor.insertRow(newRow)**
    del cursor

except:
    print ' send help'
    traceback.print_exc(1)
    del cursor
```

In the bolded script however, I get this TypeError: TypeError: cannot read geometry sequence, expecting list of floats and it makes me wonder if there's an easier way to use a cursor following the line "# Using an insert cursor to insert polyline and set value of FID to 5" to insert the polyline connecting the two centroid points.

Comment: First off, get rid of the try/except block for GIS SE posts -- they can only hide your error. You **cannot** specify a FID value.  Only ArcPy controls that on an insert.  Your `line` could be corrupted but the lack of a `SpatialReference` in the `Polyline` constructor.  Always, *always*, **always** provide a `spatial_reference` parameter on a `Geometry` constructor, *every* time, without fail.

Comment: What is the precise and complete wording of the TypeError that you are receiving?

Comment: I think you should focus on being able to insert a polyline into a shapefile using `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()`.  In other words ignore reading from your search cursor for now so that you present just a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) rather than a lot of extra code which is not part of where you are actually stuck.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It really helped re focusing and going line by line, in the end, I found it was the a problem with     cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcPoly, ['FID', 'SHAPE@'])
where it should have been fcLine instead

Comment: I've found in the past that it also helps to specify the spatial reference for the geometry that you create.  Without it, sometimes the script will not throw any errors but then it also doesn't insert the geometry because it gets interpreted as being below the cluster tolerance of the destination dataset.  Spent many hours trying to debug that particular issue!